# Calculating the area between a petal and a circle (Polar Coords)

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

The question states: 
The graph of $2\cos(3\theta)$ has three petals (also called "leaves" or "lobes").
The intersection of one of those petals with the circle $r = 1$ is shaded in the    figure. Find the area of the shaded region.

I already know the formula, $$A = 1/2\int_a^b f(\theta)^{2}-g(\theta)^2d\theta$$ the problem obviously is finding the bounds. I set the functions equal to each other and solved:

$2\cos(3x) = 1$

$\cos(3x) = 1/2$

$3x = \arccos(1/2)$

$3x = \pi/3$

$x = \pi/9$

So wouldn't the functions intersect when $\theta = -\pi/9, \pi/9$?

Can I not just exploit symmetry and calculate the integral from $0$ to $\pi/9$ then multiply the entire thing by $2$?

And Finally, would $r = 1$ be the right most curve, and the $2\cos(3\theta)$ be the left most?

Comment: Yes to all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the curves intersect at $\theta = \pm \frac \pi 9$ and you can use symmetry to integrate from $0$ to the maximum value of $\theta$, then double the result.  What you have missed is that the green area extends above the line $\theta=\frac \pi 9$.  From $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\frac \pi 9$ you are right, the right curve is $r=2\cos (3 \theta)$ and the left curve is $r=1$.  There is some area at $\theta$ larger than $\frac \pi 9$ where the left limit is $r=0$ and the right limit is $r=2\cos (3 \theta)$

Comment: Thanks for the answers to my questions but I'm still confused on how to then find the proper bounds to set up the integral. I'm not sure I grasp the concept.

Comment: The upper bound is the angle at which the curve approaches $r=0$.  For example, at $\theta=\frac \pi 8 \gt \frac \pi 9$, [we have](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*cos(3*pi%2F8)) $r =\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2} \approx 0.765$ so there is area you will miss with an upper limit of $\frac \pi 9$